# Upcasting and Downcasting confusion in java

Tags: java, downcast, upcasting

Okay. So if...

```
int x=3;
int y=5;


x=y;
```

That'll make `x=5`, right?

Okay, so if `B` is a subclass of `A`...

```
A a=new A();
B b=new B();

a=b;
```

^^^Why is this considered upcasting?

Isn't the "a" supposed to become the "b" and not the other way around? Can someone explain all this to me?

Answer (score 11):

Instead of `A`s and `B`s, let's jump to a concrete example.

```
class Person {
    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hello there!");
    }
}

class ComputerScientist extends Person {    // Does he, really?
    @Override
    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hello there! I work at the Informatics Department.");
    }

    public void validateAlgorithm(Algorithm a)
            throws InvalidAlgorithmException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When you have a `ComputerScientist` as

```
ComputerScientist cs = new ComputerScientist();
```

You can access both `greet` and `validateAlgorithm`. You know (s)he is a `Person`, and can `greet` him/her as any other person. However, you may also treat him/her specifically as a `ComputerScientist`.

When you assign this object to a variable of type `Person`, all you do is saying *"I don't care anymore that you are a `ComputerScientist`. From now on, I will treat you just as any other `Person`"*.

```
Person p = cs;
```

Which is equivalent to

```
Person p = (Person) cs;
```

The object referred by `p` still knows how to `validateAlgorithm`, and still tells you that (s)he works at the Informatics Department. However, when accessing it via `p`, *you* are telling the compiler that you only want to `greet` this `Person`, nothing else.

It is called *upcasting* because the variable goes *up* in the hierarchy tree, where *up* means *more general/abstract* and *down* means *more specific*. You're *generalizing* a `ComputerScientist` as a `Person`.

Answer (score 7):

After `a = b;`, the variable `a` (declared with type `A`) will refer to an object of type `B`.  Thus the assignment involves an implicit upcast: `a = (A)b;`, converting how Java views `b` from `B` to its superclass `A`. That's an upcast.

Comment: Do note that, although the object referred by `b` will be treated as an `A`, after `a = b`, the referred object is still a `B`, it isn't *literally* converted. All overridden methods remain overridden, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
```

The flow is as follows:

- Object of A is created using `new A()` and ASSIGNED to refrence variable a
  similarly Object of B is created using `new B()` and ASSIGNED to the refrence variable b
- The point to note here is that the evaluation goes from the right side to the left side which is why first the Right side is calculated and the results are assigned to respective variables.

Now coming to your problem which is why `a=b` is UPCASTING

- The above mentioned points apply to this statement as well, first b is evaluated which is a subclass of a. Now since you are assigning a subclass to a superclass an implicit casting takes place from a subtype to a super type which is ofcourse UPCASTING.

This link will make it more clear https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wh-WZXCAarY

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> That'll make x=5, right?

Right.

Okay, so if B is a subclass of A...

> ^^^Why is this considered upcasting?

Because that's what it is.

> Isn't the "a" supposed to become the "b" and not the other way around?

Yes, and it does. The reference to B is upcast to a reference to an 'A'.

Comment: Does this really answers the question ? OP is asking why. You repeated what OP already know.